# Sinónimo de windows-azure-storage apuntando a azure-storage

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Hace un momento, se hizo [*esta*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1204/400-bad-request-al-intentar-conectarse-con-windows-azure-storage) pregunta y fue etiquetada como [windows-azure-storage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-storage), pero hace bastante tiempo que Windows Azure cambio su nombre a solo Azure, sin Windows.

Ya edite la pregunta (las etiquetas) la cambie por [azure-storage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage)

Solicito la interveción de un moderador para que [windows-azure-storage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-storage) sea sinónimo de [azure-storage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage), la etiqueta principal.

Comment: Me parece buena idea. Además puedes solicitarlo también en la versión en inglés que es de donde copié la etiqueta. Actualmente la dirección del sunónimo está al revés: ['windows-azure-storage' Tag Synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-azure-storage/synonyms)

Comment: como se etiqueta esta pregunta como discussion o feature-request?

Comment: [\[synonym-request\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request)

Comment: no me deja, dice que debe llevar un tag de estos: bug, feature-request, discussion o support

Comment: Viendo el link anterior veo que no hay un concenso de cual se debe usar, pero sí es obligatorio uno de esos tags, yo le pondría [tag:discussion] y [tag:synonim-request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ha creado el sinónimo:

> [windows-azure-storage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-storage) (etiqueta maestra) - [azure-storage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage)

Luego, por el comentario de @EmanuelVe, se ha cambiado a:

> [azure-storage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage) (etiqueta maestra) - [windows-azure-storage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-storage)

Comment: ArtEze, La etiqueta principal debería ser `[azure-storage]` ya que la plataforma dejo de llamarse `Windows Azure` en favor de `Microsoft Azure` en [2014](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/upcoming-name-change-for-windows-azure/). No parece necesaria la palabra `microsoft` (al igual que en el sitio en ingles) por que no hay dudas a que se refiere la etiqueta.

Comment: @EmanuelVe Cambiado.